# Groovy String replacement with link

Tags: regex, string, groovy, substitution

I have multi-lines string from git log in variable
and want to replace matched lines with hyper-links
but keep some parts of the original string with Groovy.

Example:

```
commit 7a1825abc69f1b40fd8eb3b501813f21e09bfb54
Author: Filip Stefanov 
Date:   Mon Nov 21 11:05:08 2016 +0200

    TICKET-1

    Test change

    Change-Id: I7b4028e504de6c4a48fc34635d4b94ad038811a6
```

Should look like:

```
commit 7a1825abc69f1b40fd8eb3b501813f21e09bfb54
Author: Filip Stefanov 
Date:   Mon Nov 21 11:05:08 2016 +0200

    <a href=http://localhost:8080/browse/TICKET-1>TICKET-1</a>

    Test change

    <a href=http://localhost:8081/#/q/I7b4028e504de6c4a48fc34635d4b94ad038811a6,n,z>Change-Id: I7b4028e504de6c4a48fc34635d4b94ad038811a6</a>
```

Im pretty bad in Groovy regex dont know how to use grouping or closures so far so good:

```
mystring.replaceAll(/TICKET-/, "http://localhost:8080/browse/TICKET-")
```

NOTE:
TICKET {int} and Change-Id {hash} are variables

Comment: Try something like this: mystring.replaceAll(/(TICKET-.)/, "url\1"). \1 is the group that you matched.

Comment: Try `.replaceAll(/(?m)^([\ \t]+)(TICKET-\d+)(\R{2}.*\R{2}\s+)(Change-Id:\s+)(\S+)/, "$1<a href=http://localhost:8080/browse/$2>$2</a>$3$4<a href=http://localhost:8081/#/q/$5,n,z>$4$5</a>")`, here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9vKjYE/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystring.replaceAll(/(TICKET-\d++)/, '<a href="http://localhost:8080/browse/$1">$1</a>')
        .replaceAll(/Change-Id: (I\p{XDigit}++)/, '<a href="http://localhost:8081/#/q/$1,n,z">Change-Id: $1</a>')
```

Of course you have to replace the dynamic parts accordingly. Currently it is at least one digit after the `TICKET-` and an `I` and then at least one hex digit after the `Change-ID:`.

Comment: Perfect ! As i know Change IDs are always prefixed with I in Gerrit. What is the meaning of \p ?

Comment: It is a character class. Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for valid ones